# Displaying objects from a Set collection in Datatable JSF does not work

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Any reason why a such as`Set<MyObject> objects = new HashSet<MyObject>();` shouldn't work in the JSF Datatable? It works with List.

Comment: Certainly because a HashSet's elements are not ordered. Any insertion or removal in the set may cause the order of its elements to change.

Comment: @JBNizet This should be an answer.

Comment: I'm not an expert in JSF, and am thus not sure that this is the reason (or the only reason). So I'll let others answer a more precise answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As to why a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) in general isn't supported, this is because this data structure is never intented to hold a collection of objects which is **ordered by an index**. The [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does that and this data structure is the most sensible data structure to represent the value of an [`UIData`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component. The [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) interface, which represents the wrapped value of the [`UIData`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) components and holds the row indexes and remembers the current row for iteration on render and form submit processing on postback, supports from the Java collection classes only the [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface in flavor of [`ListDataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html).

After a long decision process (especially pushed by Hibernate/JPA community who generally uses [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for n-m relationships), the JSF spec team has for the upcoming JSF 2.2 finally decided to let the [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) interface support the [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface instead of alone the [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), with help of the new `CollectionDataModel` implementation. This supports sets as well. See also [JSF spec issue 479](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-479). You should only keep in mind to use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), certainly if your intention is to have an editable data table. A [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) maintains the ordering of the elements.