# var is the collection, not the item

Tags: hibernate, primefaces

I'm looping through a collection of 'RSVP' objects and printing out the value of each one's 'Name' property like this

```
<p:dataTable id="rsvpDataTable" var="rsvp" value="#{eventController.event.rsvps}"...
   <h:outputText value="#{rsvp.name}" />
</p:dataTable>
```

But I get the error: The class 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' does not have the property 'name'

If instead, I print out 'rsvp.class.name' to see what type it is, it is indeed a PersistentSet.

But why? It should be single RSVP instance from the collection.

If I debug the code and stop at getRsvps(), I can see that it's returning a PersistentSet containing my RSVP objects. RSVP has a bidirectional relationship back to Event. Would that be causing this?

I'm a bit suspicious about it being a PersistentSet too actually, I would have thought it would have been converted back to a normal 'Java' set by now, but maybe not.

Thanks

Comment: does your `PersistentSet` have a getter 'getName()' ? cause this is what jsf is looking for

Comment: Yep, my Event class has a getRsvps() which returns a Set<Rsvp> and the Rsvp class has a getName() method. It was all working until (I think) I changed my loading strategy but I can't understand what would be causing it to go wrong all of a sudden

Comment: It's in a eventController is a faces ManagedBean (rather than CDI) because I need ViewScoped, not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: try to wrap your set with a list (make `getRsvps()` return a list) and see if it works...

Comment: Cheers Daniel, you were right too, it actually used to be a List, which was why it used to work... doh!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't iterate over a `Set`, and that's a JSF restriction for now. JSF 2.2 will be able to do it.

That said, you can convert it yourself or, what I would do, you can use [OmniFaces `#{of:setToList}` EL function](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters). You don't have to reinvent the wheel. :)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712593/1363540) by BalusC.

---

As to the fact that Hibernate is returning a `PersistentSet`, that is just the way it works. Hibernate has it's own implementation of `Set`, so it can implement features like Lazy-Loading, etc.

Comment: Superb thanks, especially for the insight about the (current) JSF limitation. It's working fine now. I went mad with a bit of refactoring, changing it from a List to a Set to try and solve another problem, and that's what caused this.

Comment: @RinaldoPJr is it possible to create a editable datatable using Omnifaces #{of:setToList}. I tried this in vain. Needed clarification. Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @johny I don't think so, but BalusC can answer you more precisely. Maybe you should post as a new question.