# Is it possible to create editable datatable using Omnifaces #{of:setToList}

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

I am trying to create a editable datatable whose values are [java.util.Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). But in JSF-2.0 and 2.1 this is not possible as explained in [Displaying objects from a Set collection in Datatable JSF does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711703/displaying-objects-from-a-set-collection-in-datatable-jsf-does-not-work/7712593#7712593).

Till now as a work around all Sets are converted to [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and everything works.

As mentioned in answer to [var is the collection, not the item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109759/757071), I am trying [Omnifaces #{of.setToList}](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters) so that I can avoid unnecessary conversion of Set to List. Everything works well when its a normal datatable. But when I tried to convert it to editable datatable, it doesnt work. So, is it possible to create editable datatable using Omnifaces #{of:setToList}?

Maybe I am doing something wrong. I can post code if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that you've to wait for JSF 2.2 to get support for `Set` in `DataModel`.