# Why Set doesnt work in web flow and Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I get call in a flow a method which returns a `HashSet` of `Person` back. Then i call the `Set` in my xhtml file with the `Primeface-dataTable`. Now i want to display the prename of the person, but a error appear and say, he doesn't found "prename"...

Then i put the HashSet in a `ArrayList` and do the same. And... it works fine! But why?
Set and List use as **Superinterfaces** `Collection` & `Iterable`. So why this don't work with  Set?

Here are the parts of the files:

**flow.xml**

```
<view-state id="rcpm" view="rc/rcmembers.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="RCHtmlCache.getCommunityList('rcpm')"
            result="flowScope.members" />
    </on-entry>
</view-state>
```

**rcmembers.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable id="table1" var="member" value="#{members}"
                                sortMode="multiple" rowIndexVar="status"
                                emptyMessage="The Community is empty.">
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Vorname" />
   </f:facet>

   <h:outputText value="#{member.vorname}" />

</p:column>
```

**RCHtmlCache.java** *Set Version*

```
public Set<Person> getCommunity(String key) {
        return htmlCache.get(key);
    }
```

**RCHtmlCache.java** *List Version*

```
public List<Person> getCommunityList(String key) {
    Set<Person> comList = htmlCache.get(key);
    ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Person person : comList) {
        result.add(person);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope you can explain me this weird incident...

Comment: So the desired functionality is to just use the `Set` code to display this found key value?

Comment: No, the code works with list version. my question is, why it won't work with Set? Set is also iterable like the list...

Comment: See Adam Winer (former JSF dev) on the original rationale: [Usings Sets with UIData](http://sfjsf.blogspot.co.uk/2006/03/usings-sets-with-uidata.html). In short, `UIData` was designed for indexed data.

Comment: Try: http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/vdldoc/index.html?of/setToList.fn.html

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253340/is-it-possible-to-create-editable-datatable-using-omnifaces-ofsettolist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable works with DataModels...and DataModels only supports:
* java.util.List
* Array of java.util.Object
* java.sql.ResultSet (which therefore also supports javax.sql.RowSet)
* javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result
* Any other Java object is wrapped by a DataModel instance with a single row.
(The above objects are implicitly used to build a DataModel)
See JSF Specification.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a hint, but I think PrimeFaces only accept the List interface, hence you can't use Set interface, they are not the same.

You may create your own List + Set Adapter class by using the Adapter Pattern. It may suit very well to your problem, since you want to adapt the Set interface to a List interface. If you do so, then you won't need to convert your Set to a List every time.

Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Hope I could help.