# read persistente bag property in xhtml (jsf)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, persistent

Morning Stack members,

Would you please help me with this issue ?

Im trying to read a persistent set property from an object but it returns only one row and  I have in database table two inserted rows for such id

- How can I load in dataTable all the rows ?
- How can I read all the fields loaded in the LinkHashSet table as id,name,description,etc...

**Bean :**

```
@Inject
private Pessoa pessoa;
```

**Entity Pessoa :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "idt_pessoa" }) })
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "idt_pessoa")
private Set<ContatoPessoa> contatoPessoas = new LinkedHashSet<ContatoPessoa>();

public Set<ContatoPessoa> getContatoPessoas() {
    return contatoPessoas;
}

public void setContatoPessoas(Set<ContatoPessoa> contatoPessoas) {
    this.contatoPessoas = contatoPessoas;
}
```

**ContatoPessoa entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contato_pessoa")
public class ContatoPessoa implements Entidade{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idt_contatoPessoa")
private Long id;

@Column(length=100)
private String des_areaContatoPessoa;

@Column(length=100)
private String des_emailContatoPessoa;
```

**In xhtml :**

```
<p:dataTable id="dTContato" var="contatoPessoas"
value="#{pessoaMB.pessoa.contatoPessoas}"
rowKey="#{pessoa.contatoPessoas.id}">
<p:column headerText="#{bundle.pessoa_lblid}">
<p:outputLabel value="#{contatoPessoas.key}"/>
</p:column>
```

Ive tried with different combinations in xhtml `p:outputLabel` but with no success at all

I watched the persistent set from an object `pessoa` and it has values. The bag is an `ArrayList`

I have no reputation to post images. sorry

Comment: please post your java code. do you see rows in the table and id column is empty or you dont see any rows at all?

Comment: Ammar, my dataTable only loads all the rows empty. I do see rows in the table and id column and others columns are empty

Comment: @BalusC your comment was vanished. I dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I see what's going on... You can't use Set in data table. You have to use some ordered collection. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711703/displaying-objects-from-a-set-collection-in-datatable-jsf-does-not-work) for detail.... I would suggest create a new Method

```
public List<ContatoPessoa> getContatoPessoasList() {
    return new ArrayList<ContatoPessoa>(contatoPessoas);
}
```

and change your binding to: `value="#{pessoaMB.pessoa.contatoPessoasList}"`

Comment: yes. I had read the link you posted. The problem is when I implement the property as List Hybernate states me there are multiple fetch join thats because I joining more tables. I just workarround like this. what do you think ?

Comment: public Object[] getContatoPessoas() {
  
  List<ContatoPessoa> list = new ArrayList<ContatoPessoa>();
  for(Object val: contatoPessoas) {
    if(!list.contains(val)) {
      list.add((ContatoPessoa) val);
    }
  }
  list.toArray(new Object[0]);
  
  return list.toArray(new Object[0]);
 } *** it worked this way @Infragile ****

Comment: i didnt want you to change the hibernate binding... keep the set for hibernate but for the UI, add `getContatoPessoasList` method, it should not produce hibernate error... I am not sure why you need Object[] instead of List... but im glad to read it works :)

Comment: ***RESOLVED**** @Ammar I kept hibernate binding and set UI the way you told me. That worked fine.... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you are using wrong var variable in your outputLabel. In your table you have defined `var="car"`. So instead of:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{pessoa.contatoPessoas.id}"/>
```

You should use access your values through this `car` variable, something like:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{car.id}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

also your `rowKey` attribute seems wrong, change it like this:

```
rowKey="#{contatoPessoas.id}"
```

**UPDATE**

As @Ammar noted above there is also problem with set which is not supported in JSF older than version 2.2. So another solution is to upgrade to **JSF 2.2**

Comment: Infragile, I got this error changing to #{car.id} -> The class 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' does not have the property 'id'.

Comment: strange... please post whole your `p:dataTable` markup (update your question)

Comment: ok, now can you please post all objects on this way - `pessoaMB.pessoa.contatoPessoas` - pessoaMB, pessoa, contatoPessoas

Comment: I have no credits to post images. what kind of information do you need to @Infragile ? I have no problem in posting this but theres a bunch of code behind. lol

Comment: I wanted to check if this path is really OK - `pessoaMB.pessoa.contatoPessoas`

Comment: Updated my answer with another fix, but I'm not sure if it is the cause of your problems